# Converting a non-convex optimization problem into a convex one

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, mobius-transformation, non-convex-optimization, matrix-norms

I have this optimization problem to solve

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{{\bf m},x}{\text{minimize}} & \| {\bf m} \|^2 \\ \text{subject to} & {\bf h}_k^\ast {\bf m} = x_k, \quad \forall k \\ & |x_k| \ge 1, \quad \forall k\end{array}$$

where the $\bf{m}$ and $\bf{h}$  are vectors. Since $|x_k|\ge1$, so its feasible region is outside the unit circle. So my question is how do we convert this problem into a convex problem to get a solution in a much more effective and easy way?

Comment: Your problem is not convex and it is one of its properties. This is just the way it is. It cannot be really made convex and you will need to address that problem directly.

Comment: Why not write the equality constraints in matrix form, e.g., ${\bf H}^* {\bf m} = {\bf x}$?

Comment: $\bf m$ is a pretty horrible name for an optimization variable.

Comment: Where does this optimization problem come from?